# React navigator modal of type 'ModalPresentationIOS' on a nested screen has erratic behavior

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-v5

I am trying to create an iOS style modal with react navigator, it all works fine and opens it up when calling it from the main navigator, however when I have a nested navigator, the effect of opening it is buggy, the background screen doesn't transition to the original position from the new smaller resized position, rather it "jumps out" creating a not fluid effect.

Here is a reproducible example (only tested on iOS):  https://snack.expo.io/@functionscope/opening-a-full-screen-modal-%7C-react-navigation?platform=ios

Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you just use `Modal` https://reactnative.dev/docs/modal.html? You'll have to fit the example to your layout, but you won't have these transition problems.

Comment: @BasvanderLinden for consistency purposes, deep linking and since the ability to create this type of modal with react navigator is available, I have no strong arguments in favour of the standard modal